# Long Press Flashlight Shortcut

Tags: android, launcher, homescreen

I am developing a user interface launcher for the Android Platform running in Java programming.

Currently, I am trying to implement a way for the user to long press (Touch and hold) their homescreen and it would open up the camera flash.

Is this something that could be implemented?

Thanks for any info,
Evan

Comment: `I am developing a custom android launcher using android studio.` who cares what you are using? it's irrelevant, Or you do not understand the difference?

Comment: Dzieki za taki suchy komentarz! Wogole mi nic nie pomogles. Twoj komentarz nie ma zadnego sensu!!!!

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry, I forgot to mention that it is for an android launcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an onLongClickListener on a button. Something like this:

```
Button buttonFlash=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourFlashButton);

buttonFlash.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // Turn on the flashlight
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This should work!

Comment: Glad I could help! Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: This worked. We were able to get the camera flash to load with a button with the OnClick() method. Thanks again!

Comment: @TheEvanElement Keep in mind that you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/181223) the answer if it resolved your problem.